# Serial port data stream is different from a software than a code

Tags: c#, c++, c, serial-port

I made a C# code that would monitor 2 COM Ports with the SerialPort library.
For each event for incoming data this line appears first (in order to read the serial port buffer ) :

```
String data = comPort.ReadExisting();
MessageBox.Show(data);
```

The thing is that when I run the software Serial Port Monitor it gets me like 15 times more data than the software i wrote in C#.
It's like i got 5 rows of data and i get only 1 word from each row and most of the data i get from the *Serial Port Monitor* software is also ASCII and that data i don't get at all at the C# program.

I thought maybe to do Serial Port monitoring with C++/C code but wanted to check out first that there is a difference between the data - C# and C++/C could give me...
If not could some one tell me how i can get the entire data that goes through the serial port and not only chunks of it?

Comment: I've had a number of issues with the ReadExisting() function myself. Have you tried comPort.ReadByte() ? Try reading one byte at a time and see if you get the expected results. I've had much luck with that.

Comment: No there are no differents but it is debepdning on your port configuration. everything you are doing in C++ serialPort you can do it same in C#. post some read and write code.

Comment: You can only get one byte at a time over a serial port.  OK, usually the bytes get stuck together into larger chunks but, essentially, the COM port transfers a stream of single bytes/octets.  To transfer anything more complex requires a protocol, (just like TCP streams).